# Having trouble positioning my map art in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to create a map-art in Minecraft. The standard map is 128x128 blocks in size, so I have built a 128x128 pixel art. However, I am struggling to position myself when I create it such that only my creation shows on the map. I have rebuilt it so it lines up with the chunk borders. For reference, the map-art is 8x8 chunks. Am I misunderstanding something? Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The map does not center on the player when created, rather, the
> world is broken up into large invisible grid squares, and the map
> displays the area of whichever grid square it is in when it is first
> used. For example, if a player uses a new map in a certain grid
> square, and then moves a distance away and uses another fresh map but
> is still within the same grid square, both maps appear identical. To
> make a map that is not identical to the first one, the player would
> have to move outside of the edges of the first map (because then they
> would be in a new grid square). This way, no two maps can ever
> partially overlap and every map can display only a fixed area.

Unfortunately, there is no option other than moving your pixel art to a grid square. Open an empty map and go to the corner of it and start the pixel art from there and make sure it is within the map.

Answer (score -4):

use pistons to move it to good position

Comment: Pistons are only able to push about 10 blocks, so this wouldn't work.